# Current user not persisting across one controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ssl, controller, sorcery

I've got a Rails 3.2.8 app using Sorcery for authentication. Sorcery provides a `current_user` method, pretty standard stuff.

My app has subscriptions, they work pretty much in the standard resourceful way. Here's the abridged version of the controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login
  force_ssl

  def show
    @subscription = SubscriptionPresenter.new( current_user )
  end

  def create
    handler = StripeHandler.new( current_user )
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    handler = StripeHandler.new( current_user )
    ...
  end
end
```

The `#show` action works fine, `current_user` loads. However, right now `#create` does not work, because `current_user` ends up being `nil` in that action.

So, why is `current_user` nil when a logged in user posts to this action? My guess is something about the way sessions work over SSL, but I don't know what I'm missing here...

Comment: I don't know Sorcery but I'm assuming there's something like an authentication token or session token or so? If so, does it get sent with every request? If so, does it change or not?

Comment: I believe Sorcery uses a session token, to be honest I'm not sure exactly how it works.

Comment: Look in the rendered HTML code in your browser if you can find a session token or so before your form gets submitted. If there's nothing there I'd say it's a good chance that this is the problem...

Comment: Is your `csrf_token` being sent?

Comment: @Axsuul, looks like it is not being sent. Why isn't it being generated with `form_tag` ... I thought that was automatic? Is there any way to fix that besides manually using `form_tag nil` in the form?

Comment: @Axsuul, wait, no, it is in the form automatically. I just overlooked it. So, it should be sending with the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It turns out that I was actually getting a silent exception in a 3rd-party library that I was interacting with, and that exception was causing an 'unauthorized' request which logged the user out. After patching that it turns out there was nothing wrong with my controller specifically. Thanks for the pointers, all.

Comment: can you give us a little more details on how you patched this up?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: It's been over a year, and to be honest I don't recall the details of the situation. Basically I was having an exception somewhere in the handler object, and there was a rescue that just returned nil instead, so I was getting nil and no error message. I would guess that I went through the control flow line by line until I found the rescue that was catching something it shouldn't have, or I changed the behavior to not rescue any more, or something like that. Sorry I can't be more specific. Good luck!